# MQ Upgrade from 7 to 9. Getting DetailedJMSSecurityException

Tags: java, ibm-mq

My application was using MQ 7 with the following drivers – `com.ibm.mq.jms`, `com.ibm.mq.jmqi` and `com.ibm.mq.pcf` – version 7.0.1.6. We recently upgraded to MQ 9 and so I replaced the drivers with `com.ibm.mq.allclient`, `com.ibm.mq.traceControl` (version 9.0.0.0-p900-L160512.4) and `javax-jms-api-2.0.1` ( had to include this JAR as it was giving an error for JMSRuntimeException class which is part of this JAR). Now, when I run the application with the upgraded drivers trying to connect to MQ 9 server, I am getting the below error. When I replace the drivers with previous ones, application is working as expected.

Can someone please tell me if the drivers I am using to connect to MQ 9 are the right ones? Am I missing any other JAR files? Or is there any other cause for the below error?

```
Exception in thread "main" {_name=com.epo.core.SystemException, com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException=com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'queue' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'Hostname(port)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:422)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7913)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:299)
      at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
      at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6024)
      at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
      . . .
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
      at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
      ... 14 more
}
```

Comment: What version does the MQ Queue Manager have?  Was it upgraded or changed as well?  Can you find out what errors show up in the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG` at the same time that you get the `JMSWMQ2013`.   It would also be helpful if you provide the linked exception that goes along with the `JMSWMQ2013`.  Can you provide example code to show how you pass credentials in your Java application to IBM MQ.  If the MQ Server is at v8 or later provide output of `DIS QMGR CONNAUTH` and `DIS AUTHINFO(<value from QMGR CONNAUTH>) ALL`.  For v7.1 and later including v8/v9 also provide `DIS QMGR CHLAUTH`.

Comment: Also make sure you click the edit link below your question and add the details to your question, do not try and add them as comments as they will not format well and are not searchable.

Comment: I will ask again for all the information I put in the first comment I made to help you troubleshoot your problem, it appears you provided the linked exception, but with out the server side error log details it would be just a guess.  @a_cornish_pasty answer is very likely the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @JoshMc suggested in his comment, you need to look at the queue manager error log (AMQERR01.log file) as the queue manager is probably returning the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED (2035) reason code to the application.  You can confirm this in the linked exception your application receives.

One possibility, given the versions you've listed, is that the client is now flowing a user identifier to the queue manager, during the connection attempt, for authentication after the client library upgrade whereas it was not before.

In the MQ v7.0.1.x Java/JMS client, it was possible to not specify a username and therefore the Java/JMS clients wouldn't pass one to the queue manager.  When connecting over a TCP/IP (CLIENT transport) where the server-connection channel had no MCAUSER set, then the connection from the application would adopt the user that the channel process is running under, "mqm", and this would be authorised to connect - so no 2035.

From MQ V7.1, the Java/JMS clients will **not** flow a blank user identifier to the queue manager.  If a user identifier is not specified by the application, the the value of the Java system property "user.name" (i.e., the user that started the JVM for the application) is flowed to the queue manager during the connection request. If this user has not been granted the necessary authorities on the queue manager, the connection request will be rejected with the 2035 reason code. The queue manager error log will probably report what user id failed to be authorised.

The following Technote discusses this from a WebShere Application Server point of view, but the same is true for standalone Java SE applications:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21662193